# Paired t-test (one-tail) in Python using scipy.stats.ttest_rel

Tags: t-test, scipy

I am trying to show my hypothesis

"H1: values in array a are less than in array b"

Therefore, I understand that I need to reject

"H0: values in array a are greater than or equal than in array b"

The optional parameter 'alternative' let's me conduct a one-tailed test. However, I can only enter 'less' or 'greater' which means that I cannot reject the 'equal to' part using this function.

```
h1_results = stats.ttest_rel(array_a, array_b, axis=0, 
             nan_policy='omit', alternative='greater', 
             keepdims=False)
```

or

```
h1_results = stats.ttest_rel(array_b, array_a, axis=0, 
             nan_policy='omit', alternative='less', 
             keepdims=False)
```

But even if I could reject one of those, I could not end up with the conclusion that H1 actually holds because the means could still be equal.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your alternative -- the thing you need to specify for `alternative` in the function call -- does not have equality, your null does. There's no problem, outside your own confusion.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Think I misinterpreted the parameter 'alternative' after thinking too long and too late about it. Since it states the alternative hypothesis this call should actually do what I want.